# Keras ImageDataGenerator sample_weight with data augmentation

Tags: keras

I have a question about the use of the sample_weight parameter in the context of data augmentation in Keras with the ImageDataGenerator. Let's say I have a series of simple images with just one class of objects. So, for each image, I will have a corresponding mask with pixels = 0 for the background and 1 for where the object is labeled.

However, this dataset is unbalanced because a significant amount of these images are empty, which mean with masks just containing 0.
If I understood well, the 'sample_weight' parameter of the flow method of ImageDataGenerator is here to put the focus on the the samples of my dataset that I find more interesting, i.e. where my object is present.

My question is: what is the concrete influence of this sample_weight parameter on the training of my model. Does it influence the data augmentation? If I use the 'validation_split' parameter, does it influence the way validation sets are generated?

Here is the part of my code my question refers to:

```python
data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=90,
                     width_shift_range=0.4,
                     height_shift_range=0.4,
                     zoom_range=0.4,
                     horizontal_flip=True,
                     fill_mode='reflect',
                     rescale=1. / 255,
                     validation_split=0.2,
                     data_format='channels_last'
)    

image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)


imf = image_datagen.flow(
    x=stacked_images_channel,
    y=stacked_masks_channel,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=False,
    seed=seed,subset='training',
    sample_weight = sample_weight,
    save_to_dir = 'traindir',
    save_prefix = 'train_'
)

valf = image_datagen.flow(
    x=stacked_images_channel,
    y=stacked_masks_channel,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=False,
    seed=seed,subset='validation',
    sample_weight = sample_weight,
    save_to_dir = 'valdir',
    save_prefix = 'val_'
)

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=imf.n//imf.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=valf.n//valf.batch_size

model = unet.UNet2(numberOfClasses, imshape, '', learningRate, depth=4)

history = model.fit_generator(generator=imf,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=valf,
                    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                    verbose=2
)
```

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Hi again! It seems that my question does not inspire a lot of people. Sorry to ask again but is there really no one out there who understands well this sample_weight feature? I thought there would be someone from the Keras team itself or at least a well-experienced user. I would really like to know how I could use this for my problem. Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I am in the exact same situation as you are.

Answer (score 0):

As for Keras 2.2.5 with preprocessing at 1.1.0, the `sample_weight` is passed along with the samples and applied during processing. When calling `.fit_generator`, the model is trained on batches, [each batch using sample weights](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.5/keras/engine/training_generator.py#L213):

```
model.train_on_batch(x, y,
                     sample_weight=sample_weight,
                     class_weight=class_weight)
```

In the source code of `.train_on_batch`, the [documentation states](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.5/keras/engine/training.py#L1419): "sample_weight: Optional array of the same length as x, containing weights to apply to the model's loss for each sample. (...)". The actual application of weights happens when calculating loss on each batch. When compiling a model, Keras generates a "weighted loss" function out of the desired loss function. The weighted computation is stated in the [code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.5/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L415) as:

```py
def weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask=None):
        """Wrapper function.
        # Arguments
            y_true: `y_true` argument of `fn`.
            y_pred: `y_pred` argument of `fn`.
            weights: Weights tensor.
            mask: Mask tensor.
        # Returns
            Scalar tensor.
        """
        # score_array has ndim >= 2
        score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
        if mask is not None:
            # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in Theano
            mask = K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
            # mask should have the same shape as score_array
            score_array *= mask
            #  the loss per batch should be proportional
            #  to the number of unmasked samples.
            score_array /= K.mean(mask) + K.epsilon()

        # apply sample weighting
        if weights is not None:
            # reduce score_array to same ndim as weight array
            ndim = K.ndim(score_array)
            weight_ndim = K.ndim(weights)
            score_array = K.mean(score_array,
                                 axis=list(range(weight_ndim, ndim)))
            score_array *= weights
            score_array /= K.mean(K.cast(K.not_equal(weights, 0), K.floatx()))
        return K.mean(score_array)
```

This wrapper shows it first calculates the desired loss (call to `fn(y_true, y_pred)`), then applies weighing if weights where passed (either with `sample_weight` or `class_weight`).

With this context in mind:

> what is the concrete influence of this sample_weight parameter on the training of my model.

Weights are basically multiplied to the loss (and normalized). So "heavy" weights (more than 1) samples cause more loss, so larger gradients. "Light" weights reduce the importance of the sample and lead to smaller gradients.

> Does it influence the data augmentation?

It depends on what you mean. Here is what I can say from experience, where I perform augmentation *before* feeding a Keras data generator (doing so as there were issues in preprocessing, as far as I know still existing in Preprocessing 1.1.0):

- When feeding already augmented data to the generator, the `.flow` call will require a sample weights list as long as the input data. So the influence of weighing on augmentation depends on how the weights are chosen. A data point augmented N times may assign the same weight to each augmentation, or 1/N depending on the intent.
- The default behaviour in Keras seems to assign the same weight to each augmentation (transform) performed by Keras. The [code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/1.1.0/keras_preprocessing/image/numpy_array_iterator.py#L146) looks pretty clear, although I have never relied on it.

> If I use the 'validation_split' parameter, does it influence the way validation sets are generated?

The `sample_weight` parameter does not seem to interfere with `validation_split`. I have not looked into the code specifically, but splitting basically gets the input data, and keeps a split for validation---whatever the data is. When `sample_weight` is added, what changes is each data point: Without weight, data is `(x, y)`; with weight, data becomes `(x, y, weight)`.